# HTML 5 Cache manifest

Tags: html, caching, browser-cache

My question is rather simple. Is there a way in the cache manifest file (or In the html) to tell iPhone, iPad or other never to cache specific files?

I have a made a small webpage that also works as a web app and there is some of the page that never should be cached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can list the files in the Network section to tell the browser to never save the files.Lines from the book [diveintohtml5](http://diveintohtml5.info/offline.html)

> The line marked NETWORK: is the beginning of the “online whitelist” section. Resources in this section are never cached and are not available offline.

For device or browser specific manifest, you can not do anything from JavaScript side. You have to do additional server side detection for that.